# Conditionally disable Apollo cache normalization for certain usage of a type?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have a situation, using Apollo InMemoryCache on a React client, where I'd like to be able to instruct Apollo not to use cache normalization for certain nodes in the graph without having to disable caching entirely for that type. Is this possible?
To better explain what I mean: Say that I have an entity Person, that I generally want Apollo to use cache for, but I also have an endpoint called PersonEvent that has these two fields:

```
old: Person!
new: Person!
```

This returns two historic snapshots of the same person, used for showing what changed on a certain event in time. The problem is that with cache normalization turned on for Person, the cache would interpret `old` and `new` as being the same instance since they have the same `id` and `__typename`, and then replacing it with the same reference.

I know it is possible to configure Apollo not to normalize objects of a certain type, using the config code below, but then all caching of Person objects is disabled, and that's not what I want:

```
typePolicies: { 
  Person: {
    keyFields: false
  }
}
```

So my question is: What would be the best practice way to handle this situation? I think it's kind of a philosofical question to it as well: "*Is* a snapshot of a person, a person?". I could potentially ask the backend dev to add some sort of timestamp to the Person entity so that it could be used to build a unique ID, but I also feel like that would be polluting the Person object as the timestamp is only relevant in case of a snapshot (which is an edgecase). Is this a situation that should generally be solved on the client-side or the server-side?

Given that the graph is as it is, I'd like to only instruct Apollo not to cache the `old/new` fields on `PersonEvent`, but I haven't found a way to achieve that yet.

Answer (score 0):

To get philosophical with you:

> *Is* a snapshot of a person, a person?

I think you're answering your question by the problem you're having. The point of a cache is that you can set a value by its ID and you can load that value by its ID. The same can be said for any entity. The cache is just a way of loading the entity. Your `Person` object appears to be an entity. I'm guessing based on your conundrum that this is NOT true for this snapshot; that it isn't "an entity"; that it doesn't have "an ID" (though it may contain the *value* of something else's `id`).

What you are describing is an immutable value object.

And so, IMO, the solution here would be to create a type that represents a value object, and as such is uncacheable: PersonSnapshot (or similar).